# Java Smart Card Reader PCSCException: Unknown error 0x6c6

Tags: java, smartcard-reader

If i connect more than 11 smart card readers to my computer (running Windows 7 64 bit jdk 1.7.0-65) i will get this error when i try to listen to waitForChange() :

```
[SmartCardReaders.java:131 ] - null javax.smartcardio.CardException: waitForChange() failed
at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCTerminals.waitForChange(Unknown Source)
at TachosafeRDU.SmartCardReaders$SmartCardReaderChange.run(SmartCardReaders.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: Unknown error 0x6c6
at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardGetStatusChange(Native Method)
... 3 common frames omitted
```

The code looks like this :

```
List<CardTerminal> terminallist;
TerminalFactory factory;
factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
terminals = factory.terminals();
terminals.waitForChange(0);
```

Is there a limit that it can only handle 11 smart card readers ?

**Edit** :
I installed an Ubuntu 14 on a virtual machine and there it is working properly with 13 smart card readers.

Comment: Refer to the documentation for your smart card reader

Comment: I tried different smart card readers it is not because of the smart card readers.

Comment: Hard to tell, could you send me those 11 smart card readers so I can try?

Comment: Sorry but i can't send you the smart card readers, the transport would cost more than the smart card readers i think :) But if you can borrow from somewhere smart card readers it would be good.